# Something Wrong with App Engine Logpoints?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I really like the debug and logging features you get when using App Engine. It's incredibly useful to be able to set a breakpoint in your live code and inspect things when a problem arises. But it would be great if I could also go into live code and add logging statements.

This is what Logpoints are supposed to do, but I cannot get them to work. I am using a "traditional" App Engine project, written in Python using webapp2. I try to setup my logpoint using `gcloud` like this: `gcloud debug logpoints create handlers/main.py:108 --target=my-service "I made this!"`. It gives me a success message and an URL where I can watch the logs.

Then I go into my source and set a breakpoint on the live code, at the very same line which my snippet above indicates. The breakpoint stops there, but there is no logging happening. I confirmed that the logpoint is setup with `gcloud debug logpoints list` and it's there. Just no logs. What am I missing? Anybody else have success using this?

Comment: Hi, could you verify if the proposed answer solves your issue?

Comment: Just super busy today so no time to verify your answer yet but I tossed you the 50 rep because I _think_ your answer will turn out to be the correct one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested it (deployed a webapp GAE app, gcloud debug logpoints create, Stackdriver Debug>create snapshot...) and for me, the logpoint message is shown both in:

- Cloud Logging: using the selectors for the right service / version
- the small Logs tab at the bottom of StackDriver Debug UI after clicking on "Load more".

What I've noticed though, and I believe it is what is causing your issue, is that when i use the proposed logViewUrl printed after executing `gcloud debug logpoints create...`, the advanced log filter has an incorrect module_id:

```
resource.labels.module_id="None"
```

Depending on where you've deployed your app, the correct module_id could be different, but in my case, changing "None" to "default" fixed this logViewUrl issue.

Note: module and service are the same thing in this context